# React Component does not update when receiving an array of objects with reverse order. What can I do to make it updated?

Tags: reactjs

I have an array of objects to display in react component.

I am using Redux for my code and when I use reverse() function to reverse the array of objects. It didn't update in the component.

Do you guys know what is going on?

Comment: could you share the code in render method?

Comment: Check the doc - https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html May be you can use setState or forceUpdate

Answer (score 1):

You have to handle this change as a `state` to *force* the update of the `render`ed element.
Try something like this

```
this.setState({
  elems: this.props.arr.reverse()
})
```

[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/elrumordelaluz/yt0h9xyz/1/) click on the list to `reverse()` and update the `state`

Comment: Thanks for the comment. As it turn out that even though I reversed the order of the array. React seems to regard it as the same old one. So I have to _.clone() the original one and reverse it and return it, only in this case does react will update. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to solve this is spreading the reversed array into a new array:

```
this.setState({
  elms: [...this.props.arr.reverse()]
})
```

`Array.reverse` reverses a list of elements and returns the same array reference. The update of an array in a class component requires a completely new reference in order for an update to be placed. By spreading the reverse into a new array you will essentially discard the old reference and point your state to the new and reversed array.